# Probability of events A and B occurring in order AABB

Tags: probability, statistics

In a given problem there are two possibilities: 
The probability of A is 20% 
The probability of B is 80%

How would you calculate the probability of the events occurring in order **AABB**? (they are independent)

$P(BB|AA) = \frac{P(AA \cap BB)}{P(AA)}$

I think: 
$P(AA) = (20)(20) $
$P(AA \cap BB) = (20)(20)(80)(80)$

Using the equation I get 64% which seems too high? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is not clear.  What are you assuming?  Are you declaring that there are exactly four independent trials?  Are you conditioning on the assumption that there are exactly two of each type?

Comment: A and B are independent

Comment: Yes 4 independent trials. I am not sure what is meant by two types.

Comment: What do you mean by that?  Presumably $A,B$ are mutually exclusive outcomes, no?  Hence very much not independent.  The trials can be independent.  That is different.

Comment: If you are asking:  given four independent trials what is the probability that we get the sequence $AABB$ then the answer is $.2\times .2\times .8\times .8$ but I very much doubt that this is really what you are asking.

Comment: A & B are mutually exclusive. They are independent because A or B does not affect the next A or B. AA and BB on the other hand is not independent (I guess).

Comment: Actually I'm starting to get confused. Perhaps you are correct.

Comment: Given the sort of thing you wrote, my best guess (but it is a pure guess) is that you want to condition on the knowledge that exactly two of the four outcomes were $A$...something like that.  But, really, you need to clarify.

Comment: No the sequence required is exactly AA then BB. The reason (.2)(.2)(.8)(.8) doesn't work is because it applies to all orders (ABAB/ABBA). Is that right?

Comment: If you condition on the sequence $AABB$ then the probability that you got $AABB$ is $1$.  My calculation correctly (I believe) answers the question "if you run four independent trials on this variable what is the probability that you observe $AABB$ in that order".  I am not sure that that is what you wanted answered, however.

Comment: I understand. That was actually my initial answer that I had scrapped. I am not sure what I want at this point haha...

Comment: To be clear:  The sequence $ABAB$ would have the same probability, as would any other rearrangements.  Phrased differently, each rearrangement is equally probable.

Comment: I think @lulu is right. That will be the case if you are flipping an unfair coin (heads with probability $0.2$) four times and asking about the probability that you see $HHTT$. Is that a reasonable interpretation of what you mean? If so, say so and lulu can post the answer.

Comment: I think the probability would need to be lower than (.2)(.2)(.8)(.8). I think it would need to be a portion of the pool. Perhaps it is (1/6) * ((.2)(.2)(.8)(.8))? Since there are six possibilities and we only want one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If 
$P(A)=1−P(\overline{A})=1−P(B),$  i.e. they are mutually exclusive then:

$P(AABB) = 0.2\cdot0.2\cdot0.8\cdot0.8 = 0.0256$

This probability includes the order of the event.

As any other binomial if you were asking which is the probability of getting two times A and two times B out of 4 attempts, not taking into consideration the order, then you would need to multiply $P(AABB)$ by as many possible variations with repetitions of 2 elements you can get, which could be modeled as $C\binom{2}{4} = \frac{4!}{2!2!}=6$.

To sump up, probability of AABB in that particular order is $2.56\%$, if order was not considered it would be

$6\cdot2.56\%=15.36\%$

Comment: Wouldn't the probability of ABBA = (0.2)(0.8)(0.8)(0.2) = 2.56%. So the probability of any combination of 2 A's and 2 B's become the same?

Comment: The probability of any event in any order that includes two A and two B will be the same 2.56%. So AABB, BBAA, ABAB, BABA, ABBA, BAAB the six of them have the same probability each: 2.56 %. The probability of getting in any order two As and two B, is then 6 times 2.56%: 15.36 %. In oder words 2.56% is the probability of a particular run on a particular order, although 6 of them have the same probability, it does not mean 2.56% does not include the order. Does it make sense ?

Comment: Seems OK (+1), but your first line is strange notation, which might be confusing. Maybe something like: $P(A) = 1 - P(\bar A) = 1 - P(B).$

Comment: BruceET I just edited as you suggested, you are totally right it is clear notation.